# How can I tell whether I have unavailable versions installed?

Tags: apt, package-management

Imagine I set up some 3rd party repository that upgrades some packages to newer versions, either directly or through dependencies.

Some time after that I decide to remove the repository. How I can tell if I have packages installed that are now "stuck" on that repo's version and not on the distro's version? Is there a(n easy) way to do so?

Thanks in advance.